# Write key value to file from hash

Tags: ruby, hashtable

I would like to write the key value inside file as vals. I hope you can help me about it. Thank you.

```
File.open(resfile,'a+') do |f2|
  gname.each {|key,val| val.each {|x|   f2.write(x) f2.write("\t")} 
    f2.write("\n")}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = gname.map { |_key, val| val.join("\t") }.join("\n")
File.write(resfile, result)
```

Comment: that gave me a whitespace output
i am not familiar with ruby maybe this is the reason of error

Comment: Show the part of your input, and the desired output, please.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you mean in this:

```
h = { "v1" => 1, "v2" => 2}
File.open("./out.dat","w") do |f| 
  h.each { |k,v| f.write("#{k}\t#{v}\n") }
end
```